# Why does __self__ of built-in functions return the builtin module it belongs to?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-internals

Methods have an attribute, `__self__`, that holds the instance to be passed when the underlying function gets invoked. Apparently, so do built-in functions.

In Python 3, they hold the module object:

```
>>> len.__self__
<module 'builtins' (built-in)>
>>> sys.getrefcount.__self__  # also for other builtin modules
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

In Python 2, on the other hand, they hold `None`:

```
>>> type(len.__self__)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> sys.getrefcount.__self__
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Does anyone know why there's a discrepancy here? In addition to that, why do these even have a `__self__` and aren't like Python level module functions that lack a `__self__` attribute:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint.__self__
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

Comment: They have a `self` because built-in functions share a type with (ordinary) built-in methods, and built-in methods have a `__self__`. I don't know why the `__self__` isn't `None` on Python 3, though.

Comment: I suspect it wasn't intentional and they just didn't notice the change, but I can't tell. The source doesn't seem to have any comments about it, and it'd be difficult to find or prove the nonexistence of any mailing list conversations about it.

Comment: @user2357112 I should've noticed that they actually are the same object, I *really* can't believe I missed that. Thankfully I at least found an explanation for the first part after digging through the tracker, it does seem like an odd choice to not allow `self` to be `None` in `Python 3`, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe I've found the reason for the discrepancy thanks to [issue14003](https://bugs.python.org/issue14003). It seems it is due to a change in the module creation API from Python 2 to 3.

In Python 2, during the construction of modules with [`Py_InitModule4`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/allocation.html#c.Py_InitModule4), a `PyObject *self` argument was available that could have the value of `None` if writters of extention modules wished, as documented:

> If `self` is non-`NULL`, it will be passed to the functions of the module as their (otherwise `NULL`) first parameter

Most of the built-in standard library modules [apparently chose that path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2681) and as such the result of `builtin_function.__self__` is `None`:

```
mod = Py_InitModule4("__builtin__", builtin_methods,
                     builtin_doc, (PyObject *)NULL,
                     PYTHON_API_VERSION);
```

In Python 3, the API for creating modules changed and that option disappeared. The function for creating modules, [`PyModule_Create2`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18b250f844bf8b2d1a81c2d2dcc74e850364fe35/Objects/moduleobject.c#L162), doesn't take a `self` argument that's allowed to be `None`. Instead, it calls [`PyModule_AddFunctions`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18b250f844bf8b2d1a81c2d2dcc74e850364fe35/Objects/moduleobject.c#L162) (which calls the internal [`_add_methods_to_object`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18b250f844bf8b2d1a81c2d2dcc74e850364fe35/Objects/moduleobject.c#L424) to add the functions to the module) and unconditionally sets the `__self__` attribute on the builtin functions to be the module.

So that's why for `len` the `builtins` module is returned. AFAIK, it isn't used *anywhere* inside the function body so it's purpose isn't special in any way.

---

Props to @user2357112 for making me feel silly, `builtin_method` and `builtin_function` are actually [the same struct](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c22bfaae83ab5436d008ac0d13e7b47cbe776f08/Objects/methodobject.c#L271) so it makes sense for builtin functions to share the `__self__` attribute found in methods.

The `function` type, on the other hand, really has no point in having it since it isn't shared in any way with the `method` type.